# Is there any way to get NHibernate to emit a deadlock hint?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, deadlock

Is there any way to get NHibernate to emit a deadlock hint? e.g. for SQL server "SET 
DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW". At the moment I'm just executing a raw SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is no such thing. And emiting raw SQL seems OK to me in this very specific case.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately it doesn't work with SQLite which means some nasty hacks :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is the technique [set dead lock priority](http://csharptechies.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/set-deadlock-priority-with-nhibernate.html), this uses nhibernate interceptors in order emit deadlock priority

Disclosure: Please note that link provided is of my own website

Answer (score 1):

I used a technique based on interceptor and comments to add query hint to an HQL or ICriteria query, you can [find details here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/07/23/use-sql-server-query-hints-with-nhibernate-hql-and-icriteria/). This is not the real solution for you but you can start from here and change the interceptor to allow deadlock hint.